# Customizing Django Admin filters

Tags: django

I’m running an old Django 1.3 website. We use the admin pages to view the models. One of the fields of the model is the User accounts.

Filtering is enabled on the admin page for the User field.  The problem is that I want it to list  only active users.  Or better yet, only to show users that exist in the instances of the model.

Later versions of Django has a feature that can easily do this.  I.e.:

```
list_filter = [
    ("author", admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
]
```

Is there a way to do this in 1.3?  I hope to avoid doing an update, simply to make this one change.  Thanks.